# Android 11 Package visibility filtering: What is the best way to add package names under <queries> for 30+ package names

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver, android-keystore, android-11

I have a situation where I read data from different content providers (approximately~30 apps)
In code, I do something like this,

```
Uri contentUri = Uri.parse("content://"+packageName+"/tokens");
ContentProviderClient contentProvider = contentResolver.acquireContentProviderClient(contentUri);
```

Here packageName can be any package name signed with the same key as the one requesting it.
Now, with Android 11, I cannot query all the packages.

There is one way to achieve this which is to add package names under `<queries>` but adding 30+ package names seems impossible and it is hard to maintain when it goes above 40 or something.
I don't know if we can do something like this,

```
<queries>
    <package android:name="com.example.*"/>
</queries>
```

So, I want to know a better way to query all the packages signed with the same key (signature).
Please note: All the package names start with `com.org.<app_name>`

Comment: There is a permission QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES.

Comment: Adding that permission is not recommended by Google, and requires you to fill out some form that will be reviewed by Google. Not the best way I think.